# Недавно стал кодить, ничего не соображаю и прошу помощи у более продвинутых товарищей! Прикрепляю скрин. Помогите понять и разобраться, что не так

Tags: c++

[image: Ничего не понимаю(((]
*Сборка начата…
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Project1, Конфигурация: Debug x64 ------
1>project1111.obj : error LNK2005: main уже определен в project1112.obj
1>C:\Users\79606\Documents\моя липнинкы\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более
1>Сборка проекта "Project1.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, сбой: 1, в актуальном состоянии: 0, пропущено: 0==========*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
system("chcp 1251>nul");
cout << "Господиии благослови мою трепчину" << endl;
system("pause>nul");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас не собрано приложение - см. сообщения об ошибках в нижней части экрана. Его посностью не видно, лучше его привести полность. И не картинкой, а текстом и код, и ошибку...

Comment: Просмотрите пожалуйста сейчас. Я правил вопрос

Comment: Скорее всего, в каждом из файле ресурсов у Вас стоит по одной функции `main()`. Раз уж они находятся в одном пространстве имён, а `main()` используется как точка входа, то получается ошибка `LNK1169` со всеми вытекающими. Полагаю, что здесь может помочь либо `cmake`, либо временное изменение `main`'ов в сторонних файлах

Answer (score 3):

По всей видимости, в вашем проекте, состоящем из нескольких файлов — project1111.cpp, project1112.cpp, source.cpp — функция `main()` определена в *нескольких* файлах. Вот линковщик и растерялся — не может в одной программе быть двух одинаковых функций, тем более точек входа...

Comment: Подскажите что с этим делать. Буквально пару дней за этим делом и немного не понимаю, что к чему

Comment: Если пару дней — пока не делать многофайловые проекты вообще. Одного файла вполне достаточно. К тому времени, когда вам уже реально будут нужны многофайловые проекты, вы получите необходимый опыт. И, как обычно — [читайте книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342), в них вы найдете много ответов на незаданные вопросы...