# Книги и учебные ресурсы по С

Tags: c, книги

В этом вопросе собирается литература по языку C

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/9210255

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше бы изменить вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342 и добавлять в него книги по С, но, в конце концов, почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [«Язык программирования Си» (англ. The C Programming Language, также известная как K&R) — книга Брайана Кернигана и Денниса Ритчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0))

   Русские издания:

   Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи. Язык программирования Си. — Москва: Финансы и статистика, 1992. — 272 с. — ISBN 5-279-00473-1.
   Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи. Язык программирования Си. — Санкт-Петербург: Невский диалект, 2000. — 352 с. — (Библиотека программиста). — ISBN 5-7940-0045-7.
   Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи. Язык программирования C. — Москва: Вильямс, 2015. — 304 с. — ISBN 978-5-8459-1975-5.

   (в сети также легко ищутся и [pdf версии](http://elisey-ka.ru/c/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%91.%20%D0%B8%20%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%94.%20-%20%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%A1%D0%B8%20(%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%203-%D0%B5).pdf))
2. [Бен Клеменс   Язык C в XXI веке](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/catalog/book/795459/) ДМК Пресс 2018 (есть издание 2015 г.)
   (Ben Klemens 21st Century C O'REILLY 2015)
3. [Керниган Б.У., Пайк Р., Практика программирования,  2004.](https://obuchalka.org/20200210118267/praktika-programmirovaniya-kernigan-b-u-paik-r-2004.html)
   Это не учебник по языку, а скорее хорошая книжка о том, как стоит писать программы, используя Си.