# Можно ли писать приложения под Windows на С

Tags: c, windows

Возможно ли написать простенькое приложение под винду (по типу блокнота или рисовалки) на С? Если да, то можете подсказать ресурс(-ы) на котором(-ых) объясняется как это сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1456866/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: Конечно, можно. Ресурсі? Ну, вот гляньте https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-170 — здесь от С++ по сути только название. Или вот — https://habr.com/ru/articles/352096/. Вобщем, ищите материалы по работе с Win API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `C` по сути есть единственная такая кроссплатформаенная библиотека, если не ошибаюсь:

- [GTK](https://www.gtk.org) - кроссплатформенная библиотека, в том числе и прежде всего для `C`.

Для `C++` таких библиотек побольше:

- Qt
- wxWidgets
- FLTK

Советую использовать кроссплатформенные библиотеки по возможности, а не API ОС.

Comment: Неужели реализаций X-windows (библиотека для клиента) для винды нет? (х-сервер точно есть)