# Определить массив и ввести его элементы. Определить новый массив, каждый элемент которого равен квадрату соответствующего элемента исходного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, visual-c++

```
    int a[10], n,t;
    cout << "Enter n\n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter mas\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int b[10], m;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        b[j] = a[i] * a[i];
    }
    cout << b[j];

}
```

Насколько я поняла, надо сделать так, что каждый элемент b[j] запоминал квадрат каждого a[i]. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для комментария многовато...

В вашем варианте я бы обязательно проверял, что `n <= 10`, иначе массивы маловаты. Или делал динамический массив (если изучали) из `n` элементов.

А теперь посмотрим ваш код...

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)// Все нормально, все n элементов...
{
    b[j] = a[i] * a[i];  // Но вы их все пытаетесь делать одинаковыми, равными a[i]*a[i]!
                         // В то время как каждый элемент нового массива равен
                         // квадрату СООТВЕТСТВУЮЩЕГО (т.е. С ТЕМ ЖЕ ИНДЕКСОМ) 
                         // элемента старого массива!
}

cout << b[j];          // Тут вы выводите только один элемент (вернее, только пытаетесь),
                       // но чтобы вывести ВСЕ элементы, надо выводить их В ЦИКЛЕ
```

Попробуете теперь сами исправить ошибки? Это было бы очень хорошо для понимания, потому и не пишу, как надо переписать ваш код. Ну, если не справитесь, напишу, конечно... но я в вас верю :)

**Update**

```
int a[10], n;
cout << "Enter n\n";
cin >> n;
if (n > 10 || n <= 0) 
{
    cout << "Wrong input\n";
    exit(0);
}
cout << "Enter mas\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
int b[10];
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    b[j] = a[j] * a[j];
    cout << "b[" << j << "] = " << b[j] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за ответ! Но программу сделать все равно не получилось,  я поставила проверку на n<=10 и переместила вывод в цикл, а вот что делать с b[j] никак понять не могу((

Comment: Не могли бы вы пожалуйста посоветовать книги/ютуб-каналы и т.д. для изучения C++? Была бы Вам очень благодарна!)

Comment: См. обновленный ответ и вот этот вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Очень сильно выручили! Здоровья и всех благ!