# c++ указатели на объект

Tags: c++

Вопрос такой, зачем и что значит указатель типа собственный объект/класс?

```
class A{
};

A* ptrA;
```

И что я могу делать с этим указателем?
Не судите строго я новичок))

Comment: Создав переменную типа указателя на собственный класс, вы можете создать объект этого класса с помощью оператора `new`, и затем обращаться ко всем его открытым членам.

Comment: можешь привести пример или ссылку на статью пожалуйста

Comment: Читайте про указатели. Это тянет на целую главу в книге, это не то, что можно быстро объяснить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: А что хотите, то и делайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере сделать практически ничего нельзя, так как класс пустой. Можно только его инициализировать, но толку от этого нет. Для примера создадим в классе один публичный метод и одно публичное поле.

```
class A{
public:
    int i;
    int f(){
        return i;
    }
};
```

Пусть у нас есть указатель на тип `A`:

```
A *ptrA;
```

Пока он не инициализирован, поэтому обращаться к нему нельзя. Но его можно инициализировать. Например, с помощью вновь созданного оператором `new` объекта:

```
ptrA = new A;
```

Теперь `ptrA` содержит валидный объект класса `A`, и можно обращаться ко всем его открытым членам:

```
int i1 = ptrA->i;
int i2 = ptrA->f();
```

Если объект больше не нужен, его можно удалить:

```
delete ptrA;
```

Оператор `delete` вызывает деструктор класса и освобождает занятую им память. После этого указатель становится недействительным. К членам класса `A` по указателю `ptrA` обращаться больше нельзя.

Инициализировать этот указатель можно и иначе. Допустим, у нас уже есть где-то созданный объект класса `A`. Тогда можно инициализировать этот указатель адресом этого объекта:

```
A a;
A *ptrA = &a;
```

Здесь `ptrA` указывает на объект `a`. К его членам можно обращаться как с помощью переменной `a` и оператора "точка", так и с помощью переменной `ptrA` и оператора "стрелка".

Comment: `*ptrA` - псевдоним объекта `а`. Но `ptrA` -другой объект

Comment: "После этого указатель снова становится неинициализированным" - так говорить нельзя. Указатель  нельзя "разинициализировать". После `delete` указатель сохранит своё значение. Стандарт запрещает его разыменовывать и только.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, спасибо за уточнения, исправил.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, `После delete указатель сохранит своё значение.` — так тоже говорить нельзя. :) После высвобождения памяти все указатели на любой байт освобождённой памяти изменяют своё значение на _invalid pointer value_ ([basic.stc.general/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.general#4)). Разыменование и повторная деаллокация невалидного указателя вызывают UB. А вот прочие действия над ним являются implementation-defined behavior. Особенно веселит, что по мнению стандарта простое копирование невалидного указателя может порушить программу:

Comment: ... `Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault.` Если по старому адресу снова будет выделена память и там будет жить объект, старый указатель **не** станет вновь валидным. Т.е. два побайтово равных указателя запросто могут хранить разные значения. На практике с современными оптимизирующими компиляторами это [может приводить к тяжелейшим последствиям](https://godbolt.org/z/sfaYrhK8d). Ну а vc++ и вовсе [умеет явно портить указатель после `delete`](https://godbolt.org/z/6rrPzffbe).