# Инициализация статичного вектора в потомке структуры

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, ecs

Есть такой код, однако он не рабочий из-за того, что возникает ошибка при попытке инициализировать статичный вектор в потомке структуры:

```
template<typename T>
struct Component {
    uint32_t id;

    static std::vector<T> components;

    static T* GetComponent(uint32_t find) {
        for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); ++i) {
            if (components[i].id == find) {
                return components[i];
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};


struct Transform : public Component<Transform> {
    double x, y, rot;
};
Transform::components = 0; //Ошибка здесь

int main() {
    Transform tr;
    Transform::components.push_back(tr);
}
```

Каким образом можно реализовать хранилище всех компонентов(возможно, с помощью шаблонов) без реализации отдельного под это класс и лишнего кода?

Comment: *"Ошибка здесь"* - что это была за ошибка и что вы ожидали получить от этой несуразной записи предлагается угадать?

Comment: Ошибка - "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier".  "несуразной записи" - я не знаю, как еще можно инициализировать статичный вектор без структур, которые должны быть добавлены позже

Comment: Правильно, в классе `Transform` нет поля `components` чтобы пытаться его определить.

Comment: Но Transform наследуется от Component, неужели оно его не вводит? Да и если добавить, точно такая же ошибка возникает, даже если добавить это поле

`struct Transform : public Component<Transform> {
 static std::vector<Transform> components;

 double x, y, rot;
};
Transform::components; //Ошибка "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" все еще присутствует`

Comment: Правильно, no storage class or type specifier говорит о том, что отсутствует storage class или type specifier и он действительно отсутствует.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение проблемы, однако даже если добавить это поле в структуру(с указанием вместо T эту же структуру), проблема не исчезает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1

Answer (score -1):

- Вы пытаетесь наследовать так: `А` является наследником `В`, который
  является специализацией шаблона по типу `А`. Тип B  не может
  существовать пока нет типа `А`, поэтому не существует его статический
  член(раз и его нет).
- при объявлении Transform::components, нужно указать его тип, и если
  это вектор, то не возможно инициализировать его нулем(вектор не
  число), а возможно инициализировать как пустой вектор.

Не очень понятно, что вы хотите наследовать, но если вам нужен рабочий пример, то с учетом вышеуказанного, можете написать, например такую структуру:

```
struct Transform : public Component< double>{
    double x, y, rot;
};
```

Теперь Transform  наследник Component< double>, который имеет  статический член `components` типа `std::vector<double>`. Компилятор будет искать его объявление, а любое объявление возможно только с указанием типа. Нужно его определить как пустой вектор? Можете инициализировать универсальным инициализатором(конечно указав тип, как и при любом объявлении):

```
std::vector<double> Transform::components = {};
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный и понятный ответ, но это не то, что мне надо. Вектор должен хранить в себе члены той же структуры. К примеру вектор структуры Transform должна хранить в себе такие же элементы

Comment: Поэтому вопрос формулируйте понятно. По вашему вопросу понятно, что есть   ошибки, но не понятно  чего вы пытаетесь добиваться

Comment: Решение рабочее только в том случае, если существует только одно наследование и одно объявление static`а. Здесь я пытаюсь реализовать ECS(Entity Component System), поэтому мне нужен(нужны) хранилища для всех компонентов(без тупо класса со всеми векторами с компонентами, т.к это не совсем удобно(ведь нужен еще и GetComponent)). Извиняюсь за раннюю пометку правильного решения

Comment: Shuvi226 я ничего не решал для вас, а ответил на вопрос. Если вам кажется, что  кто то обязан догадываться какую задачу вы решаете и решить для вас всю задачу, то вы глубоко ошибаетесь. Я давно очень пассивно отвечаю на вопросы из за таких как вы. "Я задам глупый вопрос на глупом примере, и если кто то не решит всю мою задачу, то накажу тем, что не приму ответ". Да мне глубоко   безразлично что тебе там нужно господин умник....

Comment: "Я задам глупый вопрос на глупом примере, и если кто то не решит всю мою задачу, то накажу тем, что не приму ответ". Да мне глубоко   безразлично что тебе там нужно господин умник....Еще и дизайн проекта  вам  подать за то, что вы задали бестолковый вопрос на еще более бестолковом примере,  заранее угадывая что вам нужно. А вы себя спрашивали за какие ваши заслуги вы считаете нас вашими слугами?...

Comment: Моя задача - не такая уж и глупая. Те, кто знают, что такое Entity Component System, смогут понять суть вопроса. Я никого не заставляю решать мою проблему, я прошу помощи у тех, кто знает, что здесь происходит. Мой опыт с c++ небольшой и поэтому вам может казаться этот вопрос глупым, однако для меня он таковым не является