# "Перевод" кода с Python на C++

Tags: python, c++

Имеется следующий код для перевода чисел из десятичной системы счисления на другие (2-10) на Python:

```
num = int(input())
notation = int(input())
result = int(input())

while num > 0:
    result += str(num % notation)
    num //= notation

print(result)
```

Попробовал сделать его на C++. Само собой ничего не вышло в связи с неопытностью:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int num, notation;
   char result;
   std::cin >> num;
   std::cin >> notation;

   while (num > 0)
   {
       result = result + char(num % notation);
       num = num / notation;
   }
   std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Выдает следующие ошибки:

[image: Ошибка при запуске]

Код был написан Python'истом, поэтому мог взять какие-либо вещи из Python.

И, если не сложно, не могли бы вы оставить какие-либо ресурсы для изучения C++?

Comment: [Литература по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454264/176217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В представленном коде есть несколько проблем:

- Вероятно, вы хотели использовать переменную `result`, но в цикле вы обращаетесь к переменной `r`. Необходимо заменить `r` на `result` в выражении `std::cout << r << std::endl;`.
- Вы пытаетесь присвоить символ числу, используя `result = result + char(num % notation);`. Это неверное использование символа. Для получения символа из числа, вам нужно преобразовать его с помощью таблицы символов ASCII или использовать функцию `std::to_string()` для преобразования числа в строку.

Вот исправленный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   int num, notation;
   std::string result;
   std::cin >> num;
   std::cin >> notation;

   while (num > 0)
   {
       char digit = '0' + (num % notation);
       result = digit + result;
       num = num / notation;
   }
   std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

В этом исправленном коде используется переменная `result` типа `std::string` для хранения результата в виде строки. В цикле мы получаем остаток от деления и преобразуем его в символ, затем добавляем этот символ в начало строки `result`. В конце выводим полученный результат.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но хотелось бы спросить как работает следующая строка:
`
char digit = '0' + (num % notation);
`
Видимо, char принимает только 1 символ, но в данной строке происходит конкатенация 0 с полученным выражением. Хотя к result добавляется, как и нужно 1 символ за 1 стадию цикла.

Comment: @emokid "но в данной строке происходит конкатенация 0 с полученным выражением" - не конкатенация, а сложение кода символа '0' с остатком от деления num на notation. В итоге в зависимости от значения второго слагаемого получится символ от '0' до '9' (или дальше в таблице ascii, если значение второго слагаемого больше 9)