# double free detected in tcache 2 c++

Tags: c++, память, конструктор, копирование

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class SmartPointer {
    private:
        T* p;
        int count = 0;
    public:

        SmartPointer(T* pb) { // Конструктор
            p = pb;
            count++;
            cout << "Constructor - " << (&p) << count << endl;
        }

        SmartPointer(const SmartPointer& ConPtr) {
            p = ConPtr.p;
            count = ConPtr.count;
            count++;
            cout << "Constructor Copy - " << (&p) << count << endl;
        }

        SmartPointer& operator = (const SmartPointer& ConOper) {
            if (this != &ConOper) {
                Release();
                p = ConOper.p;
                count = ConOper.count;
                count++;
                cout << "Reload operator - " << (&p) << count << endl;
            }
            return *this; 
        }

        ~SmartPointer() { // Деструктор
            cout << "Destructor" << (*p) << endl;
            delete p;
            //cout << "Destructor"<< (*p) << endl;
        }

        void Release() { // Освобождение ресурсов
            delete p;
            p = nullptr;
        }

        void Print() {
            cout << (*p) << " count - " << count << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    int* pm = new int(7);
    int* pn = new int(10);
    SmartPointer<int> A(pm);
    SmartPointer<int> B(A);
    SmartPointer<int> C(pn);
    C.Print();
    C = A;
    A.Print();
    B.Print();
    C.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Добрый день, объясните пожалуйста ошибку - double free detected in tcache 2. Я понимаю что два объекта ссылаются на один участок памяти, но как этого избежать? Перепробовал кучу вариантов, ничего не получается.

Comment: Или не удалять p вовсе (например, у вас нет защиты от передачи указателя на, скажем, переменную в стеке...), или использовать глубокое копирование — выделять память и переписывать туда объект. Но судя **по названию** (не по функциональности, увы...), вы пытаетесь сделать что-то типа `shared_ptr`? Так добавьте счетчик...

Comment: Хочу подобие auto_ptr.

Comment: Тогда надо запретить копирование, только move. И при переносе не удалять указатель, а просто обнулять.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, но как это сделать, где об этом прочитать? Если не трудно, можете ссылку скинуть?

Comment: Счетчик ссылок `count` должен быть один на управляемый указатель, а тут в каждом объекте `SmartPointer` отдельный. И память должна освобождаться только когда он достиг 0.

Comment: Глобально https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342, боюсь ошибиться, но вопрос вот такого указателя, кажется, рассматривался в https://readli.net/sovremennoe-proektirovanie-na-c/ (правда, она достаточно древняя, стандарт языка успел измениться. Но принципы остались прежние.)

Comment: Черти что. Если есть счетчик ссылок, то почему вы его в деструкторе не проверяете, и зовете `delete` независимо от его значения? Да и вообще, счетчик должен быть один на все копии, в куче. Зачем имитировать корявый `auto_ptr`, если у нас уже давно есть move-семантика, которая позволяет сделать нормально - как в `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смарт поинтер должен хранит указатели лично и при передачи указателя другому экземпляру должен у себя отказаться от контроля. примерно так : `p = nullptr ; count = 0 ;`
Вот пример рабочий такой:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class SmartPointer {
    private:
        T* p;
        int count = 0;
    public:

        SmartPointer( T * & pb ) { // Конструктор !!!
            p = pb;
            pb = nullptr ; // !!!
            count++;
            cout << "Constructor - " << (&p) << count << endl;
        }

        SmartPointer(SmartPointer & ConPtr) { // !!!
            p = ConPtr.p;
            ConPtr . p = nullptr ; // !!!
            count = ConPtr.count;
            ConPtr.count=0;
            cout << "Constructor Copy - " << (&p) << count << endl;
        }

        SmartPointer& operator = ( SmartPointer & ConOper) { // !!!
            if (this != &ConOper) {
                Release();
                p = ConOper.p;
                ConOper . p = nullptr ; // !!!
                count = ConOper.count;
                ConOper.count=0;
                cout << "Reload operator - " << (&p) << count << endl;
            }
            return *this; 
        }

        ~SmartPointer() { // Деструктор
          if ( p ) // !!!
            cout << "Destructor" << (*p) << endl;
          else
            cout << "Destructor Null" << endl;  
          delete p;
          //cout << "Destructor"<< (*p) << endl;
        }

        void Release() { // Освобождение ресурсов
            delete p;
            p = nullptr;
        }

        void Print() {
          if ( p ) // !!!
            cout << (*p) << " count - " << count << endl;
          else  
            cout << "Null count - " << count << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    int* pm = new int(7);
    int* pn = new int(10);
    SmartPointer<int> A(pm);
    SmartPointer<int> B(A);
    SmartPointer<int> C(pn);
    C.Print();
    C = A;
    A.Print();
    B.Print();
    C.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, форум очень помогает.