# Как избавить от проблемы перегрузки функции в С++? (Конкретно С++17)

Tags: c++

У меня есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
#include <string>

void  CodeWriterCppFile(std::string format) {
    //Какой-то код
}

std::string  CodeWriterCppFile(std::string format, bool ints = false) {
    
    if (ints) {
     //Какой-то код
    }
    return "stroka";
}
int main()
{
    std::string text;

    std::string ff = CodeWriterCppFile(text);
}
```

Как указать компилятору, чтобы он понял, что необходимо выполнить вторую функцию, которая имеет возвращает значения с соответствием типом?

Comment: По-моему, указать второй аргумент — самое естественное решение. А в будущем — не писать такой неудачный и запутывающий самого программиста код...

Comment: Это лишь часть кода, так как полный код, который там был не обязательно было писать.  И писать "такой неудачный и запутывающий самого программиста код" не имела смысла, так как я всего лишь нашёл ошибку и решил спросить, возможна ли такая реализация или нет. Если я хочу так делать, то почему бы не хардкордить код настолько насколько мне это надо.

Comment: Да Бога ради, кодируйте, как хотите. Идите своим путем, и ни в коем случае не прислушивайтесь к советам всяких старперов.

Answer (score 1):

Возвращаемый тип не участвует в механизме перегрузки функций, т.к. в С++ возвращаемое значение функции может быть вовсе проигнорировано. Поэтому самое очевидное решение — сделать второй параметр явным (убрать значение по умолчанию).

```
std::string CodeWriterCppFile(std::string format, bool ints)
```

Альтернативный вариант — убрать перегрузку вовсе, т.е. сделать разные имена функций.

---

Вариант для извращенцев: кастануть функцию к нужному типу. Но использовать параметр по умолчанию в этом случае уже не получится:

```
auto p = static_cast<std::string(*)(std::string, bool)>(&CodeWriterCppFile);
p("", true);
p(""); // ошибка: недостаточно аргументов
```

Но зачем? Если можно убрать параметр по умолчанию и написать явно с параметром, чтобы выбрать нужную функцию:

```
CodeWriterCppFile("", true);
```

Comment: То есть "намекнуть" компилятору никак нельзя? Либо обернуть во что-то функции, чтобы не трогать тип, имя и сигнатуру функции

Comment: @Denis Допустим, что это можно. Но что проще — писать какой-то каст, что явно длиннее (и непонятнее) шести символов `,false`. Обернуть? Запросто, в лямбду, другую функцию... Но смысл? Не проще переименовать вашу функцию? **Зачем** может так уж понадобиться сочетание перегрузки и значения по умолчанию?

Comment: @Harry, дело принципа. Хочу посмотреть насколько хватит инструментария языка С++ чтобы обойти собственные ограничения компилятора. Если это возможно, то можно сказать, что все ошибки данного рода - на самом деле даже и не ошибки, а лишь пустые ограничения компилятора, с которыми он не хочет справляться. И вы упомянули lambda-обёртку. Можете ли показать как это может быть реализуемо?

P.s. Вам никогда не было интересно захордкодить код так, чтобы можно было использовать максимум возможностей, а не ограничиваться тем что дано базовым и инструментами?

Comment: Руководствуюсь принципом, прочтенным у Страуструпа: не требуется знать все тонкости С++, чтобы хорошо кодировать. По Саттеру, стараюсь не лезть в темные углы языка. И вспоминаю анекдот, когда сибирским лесорубам привезли японскую пилу. Мужики ее на березке испытали. "Вж!" — сказала пила. "У, сука..." — разочарованно сказали лесорубы. Подсунули сосну. "Вжжж!" — сказала пила. "У, сука..." — потянули лесорубы. Нашли огромный кедр. "Вжжжжж!" — сказала пила. "У, сука..." — сказали лесорубы. Взяли рельс... "Дзинь!" — сказали пила. "Аааа, сука!" — обрадовались лесорубы. Стоит ли совать рельсу в С++?

Comment: @Harry, а зачем мне тогда этот язык нужен, если я не знаю всех тонкостей языка С++? (Скажу по секрету, я даже ни одной книжки не прочитал по известным программистам и чем они там занимались). Мне интересно написание кода, а не то, что мне будут говорить "Извини, тебе это не надо, пиши лучше калькулятор". Я стараюсь обходить ограничения, которые мне накладывают. А зачем это? Вы боитесь "шаг влево" и "шаг вправо сделать", будто вас пристрелят за это.

Comment: "*я даже ни одной книжки не прочитал*" — ну, я так и понял. Как я уже писал в другом месте, чтобы стать кулхацкером, идите своим путем и ни в коем случае не прислушивайтесь к советам, особенно известных старперов типа Страуструпа...

Comment: Эм, а причём тут вообще Страструп и то, что он говорит? Для меня программирование - это использовать язык на максимум. Таким же подходом можно на Pascale писать, сидя на одних ограничениях. Если вам захордкорженный код глаза мазолит - забрасывайте программирование.

Comment: @Denis если хочется использовать "язык на максимум", то прочить книжек придётся много. Очень много. [Здесь есть список.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/176217)