Реально ли вообще изучить c++ с нуля самому?
Недавно решил изучать c++ (мне нужен именно c++), до этого знал немного go. Сначала изучал по видео урокам на Ютубе, но понял что информация там такая себе и стал искать книги. Хочу изучить хотя бы базовую базу, но не просто cout << "hello world"; а чтобы были уже хоть какие-то средние знания. Реально ли вообще это и какие ресурсы лучше использовать и сколько займет это времени. Хотелось бы послушать конкретно рекомендации, а не просто список литературы.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1

Да, я знаю про этот тред, но какую лучше книгу выбрать?

А как еще можно изучать, кроме как самому? В институте? Там кроме самых азов вряд ли что-то дадут.

Начните с руководств по Visual Studio, с раздела "Знакомство с Visual Studio".

«Несколько слов о выборе книг от сообщества StackOverflow» читали?
